# What does Sourcing of eucarc mean?

Tags: virtualization, xen, eucalyptus

I am trying to setup an on premise cloud by using Eucalyptus. I am following the following [link](http://open.eucalyptus.com/wiki/EucalyptusGettingStarted_v2.0)
Now in that guide I am not able to figure out what this means:

> ensure that the environment variables necessary for euca2tools to work are set by sourcing the eucarc file: 
>   
> . ~/.euca/eucarc

When I type the above command I am not getting any output. Does that mean I am doing somthing wrong.
Also when I try

> euca-describe-availability-zones verbose

I am getting error saying

> Warning: failed to parse error message from AWS: :1:61: syntax error

And some tracebacks
I am pasting the complete error [here](http://pastie.org/3553642). I am struck here and I am trying fr solutions from various forums and no luck. Ny help would be very helpful.

Comment: Running the `env` command before and after the command with no output (sourcing eucarc) should show you what it did.  The `env` command will display all your environment variables.

Comment: @Ladadadada: Thanks for the reply. There are many environment variables which are set (Related to Eucalyptus) But do you have any idea on why Im getting that error?? 
Even if you do not knw exactly what it means jst point me to any articles or forums which may hav the info. That wud be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**Bash Prompt HOWTO**" has the following information about sourcing a script:

**Bash Prompt HOWTO > Chapter 3. Bash Programming and Shell Scripts > 3.5. Sourcing a File**
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html

> "When a file is sourced (by typing either source filename or .
> filename at the command line), the lines of code in the file are
> executed as if they were printed at the command line."

In the command you put, you have "`. ~/.euca/eucarc`". Did you notice the "dot space" at the beginning of the command (before the "tilde")? That "dot space" is the part of the command that is sourcing the "eucarc" script. You could have also typed "`source ~/.euca/eucarc`" to achieve the same result.

Like "Ladadadada" has commented above, "*Running the env command before and after the command with no output (sourcing eucarc) should show you what it did.*".

In case you have typed the "dot space" at the beginning of the command, but are still getting the error you mentioned: I don't work with Eucalyptus, but I have looked at the error message you get when you run "euca-describe-availability-zones verbose" (`"Warning: failed to parse error message from AWS: :1:61: syntax error"`). A web search revealed the following message - in a discussion in the openstack team mailing list - written in 27 Jan 2012, by Vishvananda Ishaya,  that may help:

**openstack team mailing list archive > Re: Devstack: euca-describe-availability-zones Warning: failed to parse error message from AWS: :1:0: syntax   error None: None**
https://lists.launchpad.net/openstack/msg07083.html

From that message:

> " devstack provides a file to source called openrc with all the necessary variables.
> You don't need to create your own novarc file, just source openrc instead. "

I hope this helps. **:)**

Comment: I am sry for my really ignorant Question on Sourcing. Even though I know bash scripting I never came across the terminology (for a moment I thought it is related to Eucalyptus). Thanks for your patience and time in explaining. Will +1 when I have enought reputation :D

Comment: @bi0s.kidd0: You're welcome! :)